# takin input from a file and saving it into temporary memory?

Tags: c++, file

I have a structured array that is initially empty and has 4 data types withing, string, 2 int's and 1 float. I have a list of dvd titles and other attributes (3 other,2 of them are int the last one is float) saved in a text file and I need to input the data from the text file to my structure. this is my code, but seems like it isnt working?

```
        do
        {
           for(int i=0;i<MAX_BOOKS;i++)
           {

                tempTitle= getline(myfile,line);
                temChapters = getline(myfile,line);
                tempReview = getline(myfile,line);
                tempPrice = getline(myfile,line);
           }
        }while(!myfile.eof());
```

Comment: Why a nested loop? And getline(myfile,line) is always the same, why do you expect it to return once the title and once the chapters?

Comment: @pfnuesel yeah, it returned me the same thing and kept doing it, I cant figure out a way to get line after line :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The return from `getline` is the stream you read from, not the string you read data into.

You're also repeatedly reading data into the same place (`line`), without saving it anywhere.

Your loop is defective (`while (!somefile.eof())` is essentially always broken).

What you typically want is to start by overloading `operator>>` to read a single logical item from a stream, then use that to fill a vector of those items.

```
// The structure of a single item:
struct item { 
    std::string title;
    int chapters;
    int review;
    int price;    
};

// read one item from a stream:
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, item &i) { 
    std::getline(is, i.title);
    is >> i.chapters >> i.review >> i.price;
    is.ignore(4096, '\n'); // ignore through end of line.
    return is;
}

// create a vector of items from a stream of items:
std::vector<item> items((std::istream_iterator<item>(myfile)), 
                         std::istream_iterator<item>());
```

Comment: so does changing the value of i make the code read into different lines?

Comment: @JoshuaJones: Yes -- you pass (a reference to) an item to `operator>>` and it reads data into that `item`.

Comment: +1, But be careful about mixing `std::getline` and `operator>>`. The latter will leave a `\n` in the input stream, confusing the former on the next iteration. Add `is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` to the end of `operator>>(istream&, item&)`.

Comment: @Robᵩ: Good point, though I prefer *not* to use `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`. If the user opens the wrong file, that can waste a *lot* of time reading useless data, long after it's obvious the file is bad and you should give the user an error message.

Comment: @JerryCoffin what is the number 4096? did you put a large number so that the file reads to the end of it?

Comment: @Robᵩ do you know what does the number 4096 represent? Sorry, I am really new to C++.

Comment: This is just a large number which will ignore any data (up to 4KB) until the end of the line, as commented.

Comment: +1: This is a very neat way to initialise a `vector` from a file. The call to the constructor using the `std::istream_iterator`s probably warrants a little explanation for the new C++ programmer, though.

Comment: @Jerry: Shouldn't that be `std::vector<item> items(std::istream_iterator<item>(myfile), std::istream_iterator<item>);` (Vexing parse)?

Comment: @Johnsyweb: It should be as it is now, with extra parens around the first argument (I'd intended to do that originally, but missed one of the parens, so thanks for the heads-up).

Answer (score 0):

You should structure it like this:

```
std::ifstream myfile("filename.dat");
std::string line;

while (getline(myfile, line))
{

    // you can use std::string::find(), std::string::at(), std::string::substr
    // to split the line into the necessary pieces

}
```

You can then use Jerry coffins answer to save each piece in a `vector<item>`.